# How does the MIPS SYSCALL instruction work?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

we well understand that there are three types of interrupts:

1. Internal interrupt
2. External interrupt
3. Software interrupt

So the syscall is an software interrupt.  The MIPS SYSCALL instruction in binary form is
00000000000000000000000000001100

what happens when cpu **fetch** this instruction and **execute** it. the parameters passed before  this instruction in some registers is'nt matter here, the key question is what this instruction do itself, what his job, how it work inside cpu.

**What are the effects on the architectural state of the machine from running just this instruction?**

That means which register value affected by this syscall (instruction), which flag it turns on, in how many steps it complete its job, if it jump to another  memory location (like interrupt vector table) **how does it find the address of those memory location**  .

Comment: What does the MIPS instruction reference tell you that it does?

Comment: I assume MIPS has some table of interrupt handlers or something, similar to what other architectures (like x86) do, and that SYSCALL triggers one of those handlers.  This should all be documented in the MIPS architecture manuals.  Do you have a specific question about something beyond the manuals, or do you just want someone to find and quote the relevant section for you?  That doesn't seem like a very good question.  If you are having trouble interpreting what the manual says, that could make an ok question.  Just find the manual and include a link to it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on which MIPS processor you're talking about, but with the latest version of the MIPS32 architecture the SYSCALL instruction causes a System Call Exception which is handled by executing the code located at offset 0x180 of the exception vector base.

Specifically what happens in on a CPU implementing Release 6 of the MIPS32 ISA is the following:

- If Status.EXL == 0 then:

  - If SYSCALL instruction in a branch delay slot:

    - EPC = PC - 4
    - Cause.BD = 1
    - BadInstr = memory[PC]
    - BadInstrP = memory[PC - 4]
  - If SYSCALL instruction not in a branch delay slot:

    - EPC = PC
    - Cause.BD = 0
    - BadInstr = memory[PC]
  - If SRSCtl.HSS > 0 and Status.BEV == 0 then:

    - SRSCtl.PSS = SRSCTL.CSS
    - SRSCtl.CSS = SRSCTL.ESS
- Cause.CE = *undefined*
- Cause.ExcCode = 0x8 (Sys)
- Status.EXL = 1
- If Status.BEV == 0:

  - PC = 0xBFC0380
- If Status.BEV == 1:

  - PC = EBase + 0x180

The names Status, EPC, BadInstr, BadInstrP, SRSCtl, Cause and EBase are all Coprocessor 0 (CP0) registers, so you won't find them listed in most MIPS documentation. Suffixes following a period (.) indicate subfields of these registers.

For more information you can read the [MIPS Architecture For Programmers
Vol. III: MIPS32/microMIPS32 Privileged Resource Architecture](https://imgtec.com/?do-download=5145) manual.